# FireDac GetFieldNames without quotes

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I am recovering the fields of Firebird tables by Firedac Connection through GetFieldNames command line, however some list fields are returned with quotes.

I've tried inserting the parameters to MetaDefCatalog = MySql directive and not solved.

```
List:=TStringList.Create;
FDConnection.GetFieldNames('','','Table','',List);
if List.IndexOf('Field') > 0 then
// commands to create field in the table
```

The problem is that when the field is filled with quotes by Firedac (DBExpress did not do that) the clause if asked to create the field that already exists and generates an error.

Result of the GetFieldNames:

[image]

Comment: Ah, DATA is probably a reserved word. Bad database design ;-) Maybe FireBird stored the field name with quotes.

Comment: This is the correct reason of why FireDAC quotes the DATA field name.

Comment: @JanDoggen Firebird doesn't store object names with quotes, so it is likely the tool/library doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the quotation marks, you can use the [`StringReplace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace) function like so.

```
FDConnection.GetFieldNames('','','Table','',List);
//remove the quotation marks
List.Text := StringReplace(List.Text, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
if List.IndexOf('Field') > 0 then
 // commands to create field in the table
```